Using random PIN code in further operations
I'm a novice in Swift and I am trying to automate my app to create random PIN and then enter it after app relaunch.
The function successfully generates a random PIN, but after app relaunch - it looks like it generates a random PIN again so the PINs don't match each other. How can I store generated PIN array and use it again?
private lazy var randomPinButtons = [
    app.otherElements["pinEnter_digit0"],
    app.otherElements["pinEnter_digit1"],
    app.otherElements["pinEnter_digit2"],
    app.otherElements["pinEnter_digit3"],
    app.otherElements["pinEnter_digit4"],
    app.otherElements["pinEnter_digit5"],
    app.otherElements["pinEnter_digit6"],
    app.otherElements["pinEnter_digit7"],
    app.otherElements["pinEnter_digit8"],
    app.otherElements["pinEnter_digit9"]
]

private lazy var getRandomPin = (randomPinButtons.shuffled().prefix(4))

func enterPIN() -> Self {
    for i in getRandomPin {
        i.tap()
    }
    return self
}


You have to save the PIN in UserDefaults

What do you mean? This code is a part of PIN page, so I want to store it here for futher usages in my tests

You need to persist it if you want to access it after the app has been restarted and then UserDefaults is a good solution.

I tried to set a default in my test, but I getting an error "Consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';'"  with that code:
defaults.set(getRandomPin, forKey: getRandomPin)```

What OS is this for? You should tag your question appropriately.

To store the PIN you need to use an iOS API to store the value in application storage. There's a couple options for this— either UserDefaults or your app's Keychain.
Here's an example of how you can store the PIN in UserDefaults:
import Foundation

let pin = getRandomPIN()
UserDefaults.standard.set(pin, forKey: "pin")

You can the retrieve the PIN with:
import Foundation

let pin = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "pin")

However, since you are storing a PIN, you should consider using the Keychain to store the value.Keychain is a secure storage option for sensitive data like a PIN or password. Here's an example of how you can store the PIN in the Keychain:
import Foundation

let pin = getRandomPin()
let keychain = Keychain(service: "com.example.yourappkeychain")
keychain["pin"] = pin

You can retrieve the PIN using the following code:
import Foundation

let keychain = Keychain(service: "com.example.yourappkeychain")
let pin = keychain["pin"]

